# Error when booting from live cd

Tags: 12.04, boot, live-cd

I am attempting to install Ubuntu 12.04 on what used to run Windows XP. The original OS is all but dead, so I am booting off of a CD created from the ISO download. Depending on the time, I either fail to reach the menu allowing to install Ubuntu, or I select the install Ubuntu option. Regardless of this, every time I reach the Ubuntu 12.04 screen with 4 dots. When I use the Shift+F6 shortcut, I receive the following error:

```
stdin: I/O error
stdin: I/O error
unable to open '/dev/zram0'
```

I have never worked with any sort of Linux before, so I'm quite clueless as to what this means, or how to work around it. Is there something I'm missing, or is it a hardware issue?

Answer (score 1):

All the usual things to confirm before digging into weird install errors:

1) Did you md5sum check the downloaded iso?
  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
  Check the number against the listing in the link for your release listed at
  http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link.

2) If using a CD/DVD, did you burn the disc as slowly as possible?
  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

3) Did you select the media check before trying to install?
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck

4) Did you ever do a "memory check" (another live-media menu choice) on your PC?
Doing the above can save you a lot of time struggling with a bad install media.